# Flexbox overflowing out of parent div

Tags: css

I have a nested flexbox situation. The first one is to establish two responsive columns:

```
.ColWrap,
{
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 50px 10px 50px 25px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.ColWrap .col,
{
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;
    margin: auto; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .ColWrap {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .ColWrap .col,
    {
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
```

The second is a series of what I'm called "nuggets" inside the right column. These should wrap as necessary:

```
.nuggetHolder {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nugget {
    flex: 0 1 40%;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

Putting it together looks like this:

```
<div class="ColWrap">
<div class="col">
    <h2>Left-hand text</h2>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="nuggetHolder">
        <div class="nugget">Nugget NuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNugget</div>
         <div class="nugget">Nugget</div>
         <div class="nugget">Nugget</div>
         <div class="nugget">Nugget</div>
         <div class="nugget">Nugget</div>
         <div class="nugget">Nugget</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The problem I am having is that the nugget with all the text is overflowing outside the container.**

Do you think I should set up the 2-column container as a grid and then each "nugget" as a flexbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `word-break: break-word;`

`word-break: break-word;` keep all the text in the size the div already have.

for looking good I add:

`flex-grow: 1;` in `.nugget` - it also like change `flex: 0 1 40%;` to `flex: 1 1 40%;`

and in `.nuggetHolder` I replace the margin in padding and add `box-sizing: border-box;` that calculate the box size with border and padding, and it not break with scroll-x.

```css
.ColWrap,
{
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 50px 10px 50px 25px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.ColWrap .col,
{
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;
    margin: auto; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .ColWrap {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .ColWrap .col,
    {
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
.nuggetHolder {
    width: 100%;
    // margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nugget {
    flex: 0 1 40%;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    word-break: break-word;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ColWrap">
<div class="col">
    <h2>Left-hand text</h2>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="nuggetHolder">
        <div class="nugget">Nugget NuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNuggetNugget</div>
         <div class="nugget">Nugget</div>
         <div class="nugget">Nugget</div>
         <div class="nugget">Nugget</div>
         <div class="nugget">Nugget</div>
         <div class="nugget">Nugget</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `.nugget`:

```css
max-width: 40%;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

To center it add `justify-content: center` to `.nuggetHolder`.

Added `max-width` so that any overflowed content, i.e. over `40%` will be consistent.

Comment: you do not have to use `max-width: 40%;`

Comment: I would say it's advisable when you want to keep the bordering/sizing x-axis consistent for everything inside `.nuggetHolder`.

Comment: so for that you have the flex-basis which is 40%.
/* Three values: flex-grow | flex-shrink | flex-basis */
flex: 2 2 10%;

Comment: @Omer You're right when using `word-break`, but for `overflow-wrap` it doesn't quite work as intended. That being said, `word-break` seems to be the better way to go.

Comment: On further testing, I like my solution better as it makes the column sizing dynamic when side-by-side